# How can I assign multiple rows and columns of one array to the same rows and columns of another array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

As the title says, how do I assign multiple rows and columns of one array to the same rows and columns of another array in Python?

I want to do the following:

```
 Kn[0, 0] = KeTrans[startPosRow, startPosCol];
 Kn[0, 1] = KeTrans[startPosRow, endPosCol];
 Kn[1, 0] = KeTrans[endPosRow, startPosCol];
 Kn[1, 1] = KeTrans[endPosRow, endPosCol];
```

Kn is a 2X2 matrix and KeTrans is a 4X4.

I tried the following but with no luck.

```
Kn[0:1, 0:1] = KeTrans[startPosRow: endPosRow, startPosCol: endPosCol]
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? What exactly was the problem? Programming is typically not a matter of luck.

Comment: Did you mean `0:2`? Because `0:1` is a slice of length 1.

Comment: Apologies. This is a slang term we use in Ireland and the UK for something not working. The resulting matrices are not the same using both methods.

Comment: The problem isn't with the slang.  `doesn't work` has the same problem.  We want details - actual differences or errors.

Comment: The confusion in the answers arises from the imprecision of your problem description.  A [mcve] would help.  And if coming from a MATLAB world, an example from the might help (I have an Octave interpreter where I can test such code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But they're not the same rows and columns :-) (unless `startPosRow` and friends have very specific values).

The problem is that the slice `startPosRow:endPosRow` (for example) does not mean "element `startPosRow` and element `endPosRow`". It means "elements in `range(startPosRow, endPosRow)`", which doesn't include `endPosRow` and which typically has more than two matching indices.

If you just want the four corners, you could use slices with a step size:

```py
Kn[0:1, 0:1] = KeTrans[startPosRow:endPosRow + 1:endPosRow - startPosRow,
                       startPosCol:endPosCol + 1:endPosCol - startPosCol]
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-dimensional arrays, I highly suggest use Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
```

To create an Nth-dimensional array:

```
a = np.array([4,2,4],[23,4,3,2]...,[2,3,4])
```

The array are indexed very intuitively:

```
>> a[0,1]
4
```

You can even do slicing for the np array.

documentation of numpy multi-dimensional array: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. KeTrans is an np.array, however I'm used to the MATLAB syntax which allows me to select all of the rows or columns in an array using array[1:x, 1:x]. Is there a way to do this here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure u can do that in numpy with array slicing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
In [323]: X = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [324]: Y = np.zeros((2,2),int)
In [325]: Y[:] = X[:2,:2]
In [326]: Y
Out[326]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])
In [327]: Y[:] = X[1:3,2:]
In [328]: Y
Out[328]: 
array([[ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

For reference

```
In [329]: X
Out[329]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```